# Is there function in helm similar to 'tpl' but don't fail if variable is not found

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, template-engine, go-templates, helm3

Let say I have file like

```
it is my text file with name. It contains:  {{ var1 }}  and {{ var2 }}
```

Let's say i have values.yaml

```
var2: some_value
```

If I try to do

```
{{ (tpl (.Files.Glob "myfile.txt").AsConfig . ) | indent 2 }}
```

It will be failed because of `var1` is not defined

But I want to have a result like this

```
it is my text file with name. It contains:  {{ var1 }}  and some_value
```

How can I achieve it in helm ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't output the template action if executing it fails.

What you may do is use the [`default`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function) function in the template:

```
it is my text file with name. It contains:
{{ var1 | default "{{var1}}" }}  and {{ var2 | default "{{var2}}" }}
```

Comment: unfortunately it won't help because I want to use grafana dashboard file as a template